# (not Responding) message during heavy disk-access in a threadpool

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am a hobby programmer learning C++ and multi threading, and getting started on my first thread-pool attempt.
.
I have come to a point where the principals are working.

What I am trying to achieve is to extract 20 tags from a music file (FLAC). There may be 7000 files to scan in one session.

Each extraction is a separate activity performed in a threadpool with 16 threads,
and the endresult (a future) is pushed to a vector of structures for later processing.

The threadpool code is borrowed from:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221626/c17-thread-pool

I use Code::Blocks 20.3, wxWidgets 3.1.3, and MinGW 17.1 on a Windows 10 Pro computer.

The problem I am facing now is that the high level of disk access is preventing the app from refreshing the window interface.
The window shows the notorious (Not Responding) message.

My app consists of a main Frame class, and a Panel Class. The called functions are "free functions".
Code used to try and "force" update of the window is: Refresh() and Update().

Actions taken:

A wxTimer that triggers an event every 200ms.

A separate Thread with a while loop that sleeps for 200ms, and can be stopped with an atomic bool when thread processing has ended.

And last but not least, but still not effective

```
wxStopWatch swt;
for (auto &Fut : Futures)
{
    TagsStruct TLf = TagsStruct();
    TLf = Fut.get();
    vTrackTags.push_back(TLf);
    if (swt.Time() > 200)
    {
        // ToDo: code for updating one progress bar
        m_wnd->Refresh(); // m_wnd is a pointer passed from the Panel Class
        m_wnd->Update();
        swt.Start();
    }
}
```

The stopwatch timing is not consistent (varies from avg. 200ms to 370ms), but good enough for updating a progress bar.

There must be a mechanism to make time for the window updates.
I purchased an app that converts files.
It sometimes takes 15 minutes to perform and it has no problems keeping 16 progress bars alive and kicking.
So in principle, it should be possible to update a progress bar while the threads are running.

Hopefully someone can help me solve this.

Ruud

Added Code from button event:

```
void FetchTags::m_btn_Fetch_OnButtonClick( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    // Set Collection Name
    wxString wsCollection{m_textCtrl1->GetLineText(0)}, wsCol{"Empty"};
    if (wsCollection != "") { wsCol = wsCollection; };

    // Set number of threads
    int t_cnt = m_spinCtrl1->GetValue();
    if (wsTrackFiles.size() > 0)
    {
        Elements(false);
        auto TrackTags = ExtractMultiTags(t_cnt, wsTrackFiles, wsCol, this); // though thread-pool
        Elements(true);
        if (TrackTags.size() > 0)
        {
            // Grid is cleared in OnDropFiles()
            m_grid1->AppendRows(TrackTags.size());
            FillGrid(TrackTags);
            WriteToCSV(TrackTags);
        }
        std::cout << "i_cnt = " << i_cnt << std::endl;
    }
}
```

// --

```
std::vector<TagsStruct> ExtractMultiTags(int th_cnt, std::vector<wxString> vwsFiles, wxString wsCol, wxWindow *m_wnd)
{
wxStopWatch swf;
    // Load the TagsLibrary DLL
    if (!InitTagsLibrary())
    {
        //* Could not load the .dll
        wxString msg = "\tError while loading TagsLib.dll\n";
        wxMessageBox(msg, _("ERROR..."));
    }
    // Clear existing Vector of Futures
    vTrackTags.clear();
    // Create Thread Pool
    Thread_Pool Pool(th_cnt);
    std::vector<std::future<TagsStruct>> Futures;
    // Do the work
    for(auto &aTrack : vwsFiles)
    {
        TagsStruct TLp = TagsStruct();
        Futures.push_back(Pool.execute(ExtractTrackTags, TLp, aTrack, wsCol));
    }
    // Get the results
    for (auto &Fut : Futures)
    {
        TagsStruct TLf = TagsStruct();
        TLf = Fut.get();
        vTrackTags.push_back(TLf);
        if (swt.Time() > 200)
        {
            // ToDo: code for updating one progress bar
            m_wnd->Refresh();
            m_wnd->Update();
            swt.Start();
        }
    }
    // Unload the .dll
    FreeTagsLibrary();
    return vTrackTags;

}
```

---Extract from track file---

```
static TagsStruct ExtractTrackTags(TagsStruct TagLine, wxString wsFile, wxString wsCollection)
{
    // Convert std::string to LPWSTR
    LPWSTR wsFileName{ConvertString(wsFile)};
    // Load the tags
    TagsLibrary_Load(Tags, wsFileName, ttAutomatic, TRUE);
    if (TagsLibrary_Loaded(Tags, ttAutomatic))
    {
        /* Extract the Audio Attributes */
        TAudioAttributes Attribs;
        if (!TagsLibrary_GetAudioAttributes(Tags, TAudioType::atAutomatic, &Attribs))
        { 
            TagLine.PlayTime = std::__cxx11::to_string(Attribs.PlayTime);
            // etc...
        }
        /* Extract the named TAGs*/
        //AlbumArtist
        std::wstring ws05(TagsLibrary_GetTag(Tags, ConvertString("ALBUMARTIST"), ttAutomatic));
        TagLine.AlbumArtist << std::string(ws05.begin(), ws05.end());
        // etc...
    }
    else
    {
        TagLine.OK = false;
        wxString msg = "\tNo tags found in:\n" + wsFile ;
        wxMessageBox(msg, _("ERROR..."));
    }

    return TagLine;
}
```

Below is the Call stack with a break-point on

"Futures.push_back(Pool.execute(ExtractTrackTags, TLp, aTrack, wsCol));"

```
#0 ??   ExtractMultiTags (th_cnt=th_cnt@entry=16, vwsFiles=..., wsCol=..., m_wnd=m_wnd@entry=0x1676f30) (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:167)
#1 0x402e12 FetchTags::m_btn_Fetch_OnButtonClick(this=0x1676f30, event=...) (f:/sdks/mingw-17.1/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:263)
#2 0x417d68 wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const() (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#3 0x507c91 wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&) () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#4 0x508137 wxEvtHandler::SearchDynamicEventTable(wxEvent&) () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#5 0x5084a5 wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&) () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#6 0x50853b wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(wxEvent&) () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#7 0x508622 wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&) () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#8 0x50a71c wxEvtHandler::SafelyProcessEvent(wxEvent&) () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#9 0x57c373 wxButton::SendClickEvent() () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#10 0x56095f    wxWindow::HandleCommand(unsigned short, unsigned short, HWND__*) () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#11 0x56bcaf    wxWindow::MSWHandleMessage(long long*, unsigned int, unsigned long long, long long) () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#12 0x55988f    wxWindow::MSWWindowProc(unsigned int, unsigned long long, long long) () (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:190)
#13 0x7ffeebf05c7d  ?? () (??:??)


#0 ??   std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock (__m=..., this=0x162dc80) (f:/sdks/mingw-17.1/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/move.h:47)
#1 ??   Thread_Pool::execute<TagsStruct (*)(TagsStruct, wxString, wxString), TagsStruct&, wxString&, wxString&> (this=this@entry=0x162e6e0, function=function@entry=0x411612 <ExtractTrackTags(TagsStruct, wxString, wxString)>, args#0=..., args#1=..., args#2=...) (F:/Data/__C++/wxApps/Mtags/Threadpool.h:62)
#2 0x416ddb ExtractMultiTags(th_cnt=th_cnt@entry=16, vwsFiles=..., wsCol=..., m_wnd=m_wnd@entry=0x1676f30) (F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Mtags\TrackTags.cpp:167)
#3 0x402e12 FetchTags::m_btn_Fetch_OnButtonClick(this=0x1676f30, event=...) (f:/sdks/mingw-17.1/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:263)
```

Comment: Sounds like this might be an I/O-constrained operation, in which case more threads will only make the process slower, especially on a "spinning rust" hard disk drive (as opposed to SSD). Have you tried it with 1 thread? If nothing else, it will make the "not responding" problem easier to track down.

Comment: @Thomas. I tried with 1 thread, and have the same result. With 16 threads it finishes processing in little over halve the time compared to 1 thread.

Comment: Are you doing heavy IO on the main (UI) thread? Don't. Keep the UI thread free and update it from your worker threads.

Comment: @Botje. The main UI thread is used only for UI related commands and events. A button event starts the free functions to activate the thread-pool and tag extraction.

Comment: Are you sure you're not blocking the UI thread inadvertently? Having a thread pool and using it properly are often two different things, and the difference can be subtle and tricky.

Comment: @tadman. How can I detect if I am blocking the UI thread? Is starting the process from a button event blocking the UI? I call a free function that passes a vector to the free function that activates the thread-pool.

Comment: Seeing the thing jam up like that is one sign, but it's better to have a debugger handy so you can pause in the middle of what looks like a block and check where the code is executing. It could be hung up on a sempahore, or some blocking IO operation that's stuck in a queue because of all the other activity you have going on.

Comment: Edit your question with the code that runs from your button click.

Comment: I added the Button function  and the extraction function

Comment: Perhaps not important, but when I click the button again, the cache makes it so fast that it completes in 1 second instead of 52 second ( for 6500 files on a spinning HD).

Comment: Your call to `Fut.get()` blocks the UI thread.

Comment: @Botje. OK. Is there an alternative approach that would not block the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your futures always get resolved, you could spin on each future for a short amount of time while refreshing the UI until it is ready:

```
for (auto &Fut : Futures)
{
    while (true) {
        auto status = Fut.wait_for(100ms);
        if (status == std::future_status::ready) break;
        m_wnd->Refresh(); // Assuming these functions actually run the event loop
        m_wnd->Update();
    }
    TagsStruct TLf = Fut.get();
    vTrackTags.push_back(TLf);
}
```

Alternatively you could keep the blocking loop but do it in yet another thread, and send a WxEvent back to the UI thread when it is ready, such as in [WxThreadHelper](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread_helper.html).

Comment: I have tested your first suggestion. Fut.Get() still blocks the UI. I will have a look into your second suggestion.

Comment: Did you verify with a debugger that it was stuck in the get call?

Comment: The window shows the (not responding) message after 7 to 10 seconds of execution. How does a debugger help? The execution will be slow enough to allow the window to update. Right?

Comment: The end result is always 100% OK.

Comment: A debugger will tell you what function is on top of the stack when Windows decides your program is "not responding". I was assuming the Update() call ran the event loop and processed messages, so either that assumption is false or you have another blocking call somewhere.

Comment: I did some tests. I replaced the for-loop with Fut.get() to only 1 request (getting the result of the first Future), The even though I received a std::cout with the result 'immediately' after starting the thread-pool, the window did not respond. So my logic tells me that the thread-pool itself is blocking the GUI and therefor is the cause for the (not responding) message. How can that be?

Comment: Again, check with a debugger what the stack of the UI thread looks like instead of guessing.

Comment: I have not worked with debuggers before. So I do not know how to do that :-(.

Comment: I edited my question with what I think is what you are asking for.

Comment: Run the program with a debugger attached, then tell your debugger to break/pause right when windows tells you the process is not responding.  That should tell you why it is not running its event loop.

Comment: When running with the debugger I do not see the message, but the gui is locked. There are 2 lines in the call stack.  #0 0x7ffeededfaa1 ?? () (??:??)
                                          #1 0x7ffeedf0d49b ?? () (??:??)

Comment: Nothing else? Surely there are other threads running? It is curious that you would have stack frames not associated with any known module.

Comment: The log states: Trying to interrupt process with pid: 5496; child pid: 5496 gdb pid: 7796      In ?? () ()     Continuing...

Comment: I am running it again. 24 threads in the running threads view. on is active. The thread_id changes over time. The text is e.g. 27 Thread 7012.0x2f58 0x00007ffeededfaal in ?? (). When 27 changes then also 0x2f58 changes.

Comment: If you're using gdb, `thread apply all bt` will give you all thread stacks

Comment: Code::Blocks with gdb. The "Debugger initialization commands" in C::B are now "set follow-fork-mode child" and "thread apply all bt". The callstack and thread view are the same as before.

Comment: You may have to switch between threads somewhere ? I've never used that ide.

Comment: I tried gdb from the command prompt, but receive an error: gdb.exe: warning: Couldn't determine a path for the index cache directory.

Comment: I do not mind handing over the project. There is nothing secret in there.

Comment: I don't have a Windows box to reproduce your error on anyway, and I don't know what is wrong with your GDB installation. Perhaps you should do the waiting in a separate thread and notify the main thread with the wxthreadhelper then.

Comment: I had a look at wxThreadhelper, but do not quite understand it (yet). But I will try.

Comment: The key point is to have the thread update a shared datastructure such as a queue of TagsStruct  with appropriate locking, and send an event back to the main thread to tell it to read from the datastructure. The UI event loop processes both regular UI and the wxEVT_THREAD messages.

Comment: Hmm. I will need to run the entire thread-pool in wxThreadHelper. The window freezes even when I comment out the for-loop with  Fut.wait() and the for-loop with Fut.Get(). (which leaves only the tread-pool at work, pushing Futures into a vector).

Comment: It would not surprise me if the thread pool destructor waits until all threads are done. Try making the threadpool a static or global variable instead.

Comment: Sadly, static nor global made a difference.